# Resume PHP function execution after GUI

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm new to PHP, and I'm trying to achieve this:

[image]

The problem is, I don't even know is it possible using any combination of PHP/Javascript or JQuery. Whenever user is redirected to UI, the function state is lost and cannot be resumed from where it left, after the successful completion of UI tasks.

Is there any possible solution to achieve this? I know I can create a new method and call that after user clicks OK. But my requirement is to not breakdown the function in further modules.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes, possibly, what you are looking for is calling js script and html within php function, it is possible. but thats not recommended. better try ajax here. js script points a ajax file with php function, function returns some value, with the parsed value, again triggering js script for confirmation yes/no.

Comment: PHP does not work like that. When you make a request, the web server picks it up and gives it to PHP. Then PHP does what it needs to do. When it's done it returns the output to the webserver and the webserver responses with the php output. After returning the output PHP is done and won't get executed until a new request is made.

Comment: You can use $_SESSION to store information, but I recommend to save the information in a database for furter use.

Comment: For this type of functionality you have to use Ajax. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

No, PHP is a scripting language: script runs, does something and dies. And so on every request. Make your code stateless, we have files and DBs and other storages for state.